# onClick event not working properly, how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I've built this react component designed to play a flashcards game. Any time the user clicks check button the app checks the if te answer is correct. However, sometimes I click the button and nothing happens. I have no clue why.

Here's the component source code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Flashcard from "../Flashcard/Flashcard";
import quiz from "./quiz.css"

const Quiz = () => {
    const [answer, setAnswer] = useState('');
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
    const [quiz, setQuiz] = useState({ Flashcards: [{word: '', translation: '', id: 0}], Title: '', id: '' })
    const [correctAnswers, setCorrectAnswers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (localStorage.getItem("currentQuiz") !== null) {
            setQuiz(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentQuiz")));
            setIndex(Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.Flashcards.length));
        }
    }, [])

    const onAnswerChange = (event) => {
        setAnswer(event.target.value);
    }

    const check = () => {
        if(quiz.Flashcards[index].translation === answer) {
            correctAnswers.push(quiz.Flashcards[index]);
            setCorrectAnswers(correctAnswers);
            if (quiz.Flashcards.length > 1){
                quiz.Flashcards.splice(index, 1);
                setIndex(Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.Flashcards.length));
            }
        }
        else {
            setIndex(Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.Flashcards.length));
        }
    }


    return (
        <div className="quiz">
            <div className="quiz-top">
                <button>Reset</button>
                <p className="quiz-p">{`${correctAnswers.length}/${correctAnswers.length + quiz.Flashcards.length}`}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="quiz-middle">
                <div className="flashcard-wrapper">
                    <div className="flashcard-top">
                        <p>{quiz.Title}</p>
                        <p>like</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="flashcard-middle">
                        <p>{quiz.Flashcards[index].word}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="flashcard-bottom">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Answer.. " value={answer} onChange={event => onAnswerChange(event)} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="quiz-bottom">
                <button onClick={check} >Check!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Quiz;
```

[This is the UI of the component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cukwu.png)

Honestly, I have no clue what is causing this issue.

Comment: My best guess would be that it does not work when you only have 1 card left. Since you do not `setIndex `  if that is the case. 
I would recommend som old fashion caveman debugging and add some console.log to figure out which edge case that causes the issue. 
Side note: don't use splice directly on the state `quiz.Flashcards.splice`. You should NEVER mutate the state directly only using the set function. In your case `setQuiz `

Comment: It would be great if you can provide some working snippets showcasing your issue. Also, what exactly is the issue that you face while clicking on the button? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Nothing happens, no error. I expect it to check the answer and go to the next card.

Comment: @Disco seems that not using setQuiz was causing the problem. Solved it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that not using setQuiz function to modify the state was causing the problem. Just added that and it worked.

Added the answer in case anyone has a similar issue.